# The jsf system keeps showing expired message after A4J.AJAX.onExpired used

Tags: jsf, richfaces, session-timeout

I use the code below to handle the session expiration in my system, but there is a bug that sometimes the message will keep coming out even if the user just logon in one second.

```html
<ui:define name="script">
    <script language="javascript">        
        A4J.AJAX.onExpired = function(loc, expiredMsg) {
            alert( '#{m.message_a4j_session_expired}' );
        }        
    </script>   
</ui:define>
```

The framework is JSF1.1 + Richfaces3.3

My question is how can I analyze this bug and find a solution, or is there some other solution for replacement to handle the session expiration?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza, thank a lot for your format.